# OTP detection in an app WebView

Tags: android, webview, detection, one-time-password

Is there any way to automatically detect OTP in a webview? 
There is a mobile no. to be verified using a an OTP and OTP is to be detected in in app webview.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get OTP via sms and notify by receiver, then inside webview whichever input text inside you want to add your OTP there you need to do something like this?

```
String otp = "OTP_FROM_YOUR_RECEIVER";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('otp_input').value = '"+otp+"';");
```

Above code is just example you need to change as per your requirements and all.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code in Kotlin:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            mWebView!!.evaluateJavascript(getString(R.string.fill_otp) + "\"$extractedOTP\";") { Log.e(TAG, it) }
        } else {
            mWebView!!.loadUrl(getString(R.string.fill_otp) + "\"$extractedOTP\";")
        }
```

Put "fill_otp" in strings file:

```
<string name="fill_otp">javascript: function getInputs() {
    var ary = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\");

    for (var i=0; i&lt;inputs.length; i++)
        {
            if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == \"password\"||
            inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == \"tel\"||
            inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == \"number\"||
            inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == \"text\"){

                if(!inputs[i].hidden&amp;&amp;!inputs[i].disabled){
                    ary.push(inputs[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return ary;
    }
    var array= getInputs();
    array[0].value=</string>
```